# iOS UIViewController trouble opening another uivewcontoller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers, one is main and second is detail. Whenever I click on one cell of uitableview in the main view controller, it should immediately show detail view controllers that has either empty cells or cells of some content in a uitableview. My codes work perfectly in one of my apps. However, when I copied whole codes and adapted the file names, nothing works, i.e. it does not present detail view controller, even though the debugger console showed it SHOULD work.

What could cause this trouble?

Comment: If you've changed the names of the viewController.m and .h files then the nib may have lost it's association to it's fileowner. Open the xib file, click on "File's Owner" down the left and using the right hand bar check that it's set to the right class.

Comment: @gre I dont use xib files, as I program everything manually. So what other things could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by copying the content of the files that feed my table view into new files with new names.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the "Refactor" option to rename the files, if not try refactoring the files from a fresh copy of your old project. Please post more info "nothing works" is a little too vague.

Comment: What is Refactor? Does this function exist in Xcode? With "nothing works", I mean that nothing happens when I click on whichever cells on Main View Controller, which should view Detail View Controller.

Comment: I found "Refactoring" function in Xcode, however it does not let me use "Rename" option, only "Extract" option.